# Freedom of second order differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Usually for second order differential equations, we get a general solution with 2 constants that are obtained by using the boundary conditions. What about for a coupled pair of second order differential equations? Would I be right to think that the same applies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have $4$ constants, which can be taken as the values of the dependent variables and their derivatives at the initial point.

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you.